# How to define field specific error message or overwrite the default one for a custom validation rule used in a FormRequest in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, localization

I have created a custom validation rule and I am using it to validate a data field in a **FormRequest**.

However, I would like to use a different message for this field and not the default message that is set in the Rule's **message()** method.

So, I tried using the method **messages()** inside of the **FormRequest** using a key of the field name and the rule (in snake case)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'clients' => [
            new ClientArrayRule(),
        ],
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'clients.client_array_rule' => "clients should be a valid client array"
    ];
}
```

The error message did not change, I investigated a little inside the code of the validator and I found out that for custom rules, it uses the method **validateUsingCustomRule** that doesn't seem to care about custom messages.

Any ideas on how it can be overwritten or what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you show us the content of your `rules()` method?

Comment: @DenisPriebe I edited the question adding rules method

Answer (score 2):

For custom message on Laravel:

```
 /**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'age' => 'required|gte:4',

    ];
}


/**
 * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'username.required' => 'Custom message',
        'password.required' => 'Custom message',
        'email.required' => 'Custom message',
        'age.required' => 'Custom message',
        'age.gte' => 'Custom message'
    ];
}
```

Comment: This is the case when using Laravel built in rules and it works perfectly, but in my case, the validation rule is a custom one.